# Is it possible to have a landing page based on the visitors location?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation

I am a new coder in the midst of building my first web application using the RAILS web framework.

From a technical perspective, Is it possible to have my landing page "change" based on a visitors location. (IP address or something else)

If so, how easily can this be done.